# Codename One: Picker button texts Cancel/OK not localized on Android device

Tags: string, localization, codenameone, picker

I have a string Picker, created as shown below.

```
Picker pick = new Picker();
pick.setUIID("MyTextField");
pick.getAllStyles().setFont(myFont);
pick.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
pick.setStrings("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "15");
pick.setPreferredTabIndex(-1);
```

The picker popup has buttons with texts Cancel and OK.
My app is localized with keys for Cancel and OK.
Localization works fine in the simulator for iOS and Android, and on iOS devices.
But not on an Android device, there Cancel and OK are shown only in English.
See the partial screenshots for iPhone X (correct: translation to Dutch):

[image]
and Nexus 5 (incorrect: no translation to Dutch, texts in English):

[image].

I also use a Date Picker and that one is localized correctly on Nexus 5.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the button texts being converted to upper case? (Android button text decoration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the picker to use lightweight picker mode. In that case it will look the same on all platforms and you will be able to provide the localization strings yourself.

We don't localize the native pickers at this time and I'm not sure if it's something we can/should do realistically.

Comment: Thanks, lightweight does the job. So actually this is a bug in the native pickers on the Android device: date pickers are in Dutch and string pickers in English. It was a bit confusing that "native" pickers localized correctly on iOS devices.

Comment: So my only problem left with localization is the 'Done' button on the popup keyboard for a multi-line textarea. Hiding the button bar does not work for me. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try adding the word "done" to the resource bundle?

Comment: I tried adding "done" and it works, thanks. That is a bit unexpected since "Done" was already present in my resource bundle and that is what was shown.